# Is there an Affiliate plugin or way to track affiliate links with 301 redirects for Ghost CMS

Tags: ghost-blog, affiliate

Currently Im using 301 redirects for affiliate links in Ghost CMS. But with ghostboard analytics I can not seem to track traffic.

So two questions. Is there a better way for affiliate links within Ghost?
And how can I track these in a right way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I did this by connecting the website to Cloudflare, then served Google Analytics through Zaraz (available in free plan).

After this, I set up a click listener for website links with rel=nofollow (a[rel="nofollow"] selector) for tracking affiliate link clicks in Google Analytics without additional software.

Note: New Google Analytics (4) may require some experimentation to see clicks. Set up trigger in Zaraz (Action Name > Event Name = "Aff Click Track Property: href") for GA to create a new event and easily track clicks in Google Analytics.